# Error: 0x80040308 Cannot create Qbxmlrp2 com component

Tags: c++, mfc, quickbooks, qbxml

I am testing connection with QuickBooks' QBFC15 but the sample codes in C++ give the same error. I have tried copying the QBXMLRP2.DLL file that come with the sample projects and replacing it in the common files for both x64 and x86 but still am unable to connect. some one point to me the right direction to fix this

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: What's the error message? Can you post your code?

Comment: Well, I had installed QBSDK x64 instead of x86. I learnt that most QuickBooks versions work well with x86 platiform. Installing QBSDKx86 solved the matter. Those sample codes are found [here](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/develop/sample-applications-and-code#itemquery-desktop)